# Use a bitmap as a font on website

Tags: html, css, fonts, bitmap

I'm hoping to use the same font we use in our native software on an internal web tool.

Unfortunately our existing software uses a single bitmap with characters defined in a grid, like this example: http://realmike.org/bmpfonts/samplefont.gif The CSS @font-face rule doesn't work for these types of fonts, so I've been researching how I could convert my bitmap sprite sheet into a suitable format (ttf/otf/woff/etc). Unfortunately I've not been able to find anything that doesn't involve a lot of manual work.

Is there any way I can do either of the following?

- Convert my bitmap spritesheet into a format suitable for use in CSS @font-face rule. I am aware that the formats I've mentioned are vector fonts with fancy kerning support etc, and so it's not possible to get a fully featured font from a mere bitmap file. This doesn't bother me, a font that works at one size with fixed-width spacing would be fine.
- Use my bitmap spritesheet as a font. Some additional JS programming to pick apart the bitmap would be fine if I can still select text, support forms etc.

Comment: Convert your bitmap to an OpenType font - it's a surprisingly little known fact that real OpenType fonts don't *need* to be vectors, they can be Embedded Bitmap Data, too. So you get 1:1 bitmap fonts as long as you remember to set the right font size. A tool like FontForge (the big daddy of free font editing software) should get you there.

Comment: Thanks! That solution involves a bit of annoying manual work because there doesn't seem to be any way to import more than one glyph at a time in FontForge, but it is considerably better than what I've thought of.

Comment: fontforge has a python bridge, so scripting a batch import should remove the "manual hassle" part.

Comment: Oh wow, that's cool. Thanks